# Can the saturation of an OPA influence its input?

Tags: operational-amplifier, saturation, instrumentation

I am working with an analogue processing circuit, finishing with 2 non-inverting OPA one after the other.

To characterise the noise produced by the circuit, I wanted to add a third non-inverting OPA at the end of the circuit, in order to amplify x10.

Since the circuit is made to amplify just before saturation, I was wondering if the saturation of the third OPA could have an action on its input (i.e. does the measure after the second OPA will be the same with or without the third OPA following it).

As the third OPA has an infinite input impedance and that we are in a non-inverting sketch, I think that it won't change anything, but I am not sure about it.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about optical parametric amplifiers or something else? Because you can't really use resistors to set the gain of an OPA like you show in your diagram.

Comment: What do you mean ? You will have a gain of G=1+R2/R1 at the end, won't you ?

Comment: Not if you're using an OPA (optical parametric amplifier) .

Answer (score 1):

It certainly can - depending on the opamp.

An opamp in linear operation maintains the same voltage on both inputs. With a bipolar input stage, that leaves Vbe on both input transistors the same.

Outside the linear range that is no longer the case.

Consider the case where saturating the output leaves Vbe too low on the feedback input. It follows that Vbe on the signal input can be too high, leaving that base-emitter junction conducting heavily, acting as a forward biased diode, where it should be a high impedance input.

In your case, feed the third opamp from the measurement point via a high value resistor (maybe 10k) : this will both buffer the measurement point from any such effect, and (by measuring both ends of the resistor) indicate whether this problem is actually occurring, with minimal effect on the signal seen by the third opamp. (Check R and the opamp's Cin meet your bandwidth requirements, of course)

Comment: If I get it well, you think the best solution is to put a resistor before the +input of the third, and measure the current that go in it (the 3rd OPA) ?